# How to upload files to Amazon S3 using an access key id and secret access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to upload some static HTML and CSS files to [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), and have been given an Access Key ID as well as a Secret Access Key.

I've signed up for AWS, how to I upload stuff?

Comment: Need more detail about your intention - do you want to upload to an S3 bucket? To an EC2 instance? To an EB environment?

Comment: Where do you find your Access Key ID and Secret?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are comfortable using the command line, the most versatile (and enabling) approach for interacting with (almost) all things AWS is to use the excellent [AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) - it meanwhile covers most services' APIs, and it also features *higher level S3 commands* that ease dealing with your use case considerably, see the [AWS CLI reference for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html) (the lower level commands are in [s3api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html)) - specifically you are likely interested in:

- [cp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) - *Copies a local file or S3 object to another location locally or in S3*
- [sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) - *Syncs directories and S3 prefixes.*

I use the latter to deploy [static websites hosted on S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) by simply syncing what's changed, convenient and fast. Your use case is covered by the first of several [Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#examples) (more fine grained usage with `--exclude`, `--include` and prefix handling etc. is available):

> The following sync command syncs objects under a specified prefix and
>   bucket to files in a local directory by uploading the local files to
>   s3. [...]
>
> ```
> aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket
> ```

While the AWS CLI supports the regular [AWS Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-installing-credentials) handling via environment variables, you can also configure [Multiple Configuration Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles) for yourself and other AWS accounts and switch as needed:

> The AWS CLI supports switching between multiple profiles stored within the configuration file. [...] Each profile uses different credentials—perhaps from two different IAM users—and also specifies a different region. The first profile, default, specifies the region us-east-1. The second profile, test-user, specifies us-west-2. Note that, for profiles other than default, you must prefix the profile name with the string, profile.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to upload to S3 storage, there are some good free apps out there. If you google for "CloudBerry Labs" they have a free "S3 Explorer" application which lets you drag and drop your files to your S3 storage. When you first install and launch the app, there will be a place to configure your connection. That's where you'll put in your AccessKey and SecretKey.

Comment: S3 Explorer looks promising! I'm on OSX though, is there any similar app for that platform?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the AWS-CLI, there are a number of 'S3 browsers'. These act very much like FTP clients, showing folder structure and files on the remote store, and allow you to interact much like FTP by uploading and downloading.

This isn't the right forum for recommendations, but if you search the usual places for well received s3 browsers you'll find plenty of options.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a handful of files to S3 (the cloud storage and content distribution system), you can log in to use the AWS console S3 application.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?#

There's also tonnage of documentation on AWS about the various APIs.

Comment: Thing is though, I don't want to upload to my own bucket. I have an Access Key ID and secret access key to another bucket that I have to upload to.